RF jammer module power measurement using a spectrum analyzer
I have an RF jammer module that works at 2390-2510 MHz. The voltage is 24-28 V and it can transmit up to 50 W.
When I use a spectrum analyzer,  the value is around -20 dBm. If I'm not mistaken, -20 dBm is far below 50 W (50 W is around 47 dBm.) I need some advice to further understand this power measurement.
This is the display of my spectrum analyzer:


Could you please put a link to the product's datasheet? Also, could you show a photo of your measurement setup?

Ditto the previous comment. Also, are you aware that most spectrum analyzer inputs are not rated for power inputs of 50 watts? Usually 1 watt or so is the limit.

by the way, if you plug in a formatted USB thumb drive into the USB port, and use the SA's "screenshot" functionality, you get sharp pictures without reflections, in case you need these for, say, including in a thesis or posting online.

If this thing really delivers 50 W, then you have fried your measurement equipment: the Owon XSA1075P tolerates no more than 1 W before it gets damaged, even with the internal 40 dBm attenuation.
Because you knew that, you certainly included some 60 dB attenuation or so in line, I hope, and just forgot to subtract these out?
Alternatively: you find cheap jammers on Aliexpress. Not only are they totally unethical devices that nobody, including prison administrations, should be using, their marketing material's numbers of course have not much to do with reality. What you're showing here looks suspiciously well-contained within the desired band, so I'm guessing this is actually government-grade stuff, and you shouldn't be asking us, but the supplier.

Hey, thanks for your answer. I forgot to highlight my attenuator at my question. I think it is why my measurement is confusing.
